# C# LPUTF8Str string marshaling does not appear to read string correctly from memory

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, utf-8

`LPUTF8Str` string marshaling in C# simply does not work for me. I feel like I'm can't be understanding its use case correctly, but after poring over the documentation and doing various other tests, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

### Context

First of all, to state my base (possibly incorrect) understanding of character encodings and why C# needs to convert them, in case something is wrong here:

- Standard C/C++ strings (`const char*` and `std::string` respectively) use single-byte characters by default, on Windows and elsewhere. You can have strings with two-byte characters, but these are only used if you choose to use `std::wstring` (which I am not doing).
- The default Windows single-byte character encoding is ANSI (7-bit ASCII + an extra set of characters that uses the 8th bit).
- Unicode is the mapping of printable characters to code points (ie. to unique numbers). Strings of Unicode code points are commonly encoded using conventions such as:

  - UTF-8: mostly one byte per character for English, with special bytes specifying where a chain of more than one byte should form a single character (for the more funky ones). 7-bit ASCII is a subset of the UTF-8 encoding.
  - UTF-16: two bytes per character, with similar (but rarer) continuation patterns for the *really* funky characters.
  - UTF-32: four bytes per character, which is basically never used for English and adjacent languages because it's not a very memory-efficient encoding.
- To write non-ASCII characters in C/C++ strings, you can encode the literal UTF-8 bytes using `\xhh`, where `hh` is the hex encoding of the bytes. Eg. `"\xF0\x9F\xA4\xA0"` equates to "".
- C# encodes all managed strings using two-byte characters - I'm unsure if this is explicitly UTF-16, or some other Microsoft encoding. When a C/C++ string is passed to C#, it needs to be converted from single-byte (narrow) characters to two-byte (wide) characters.
- Microsoft abuses the term "Unicode". They refer to two-byte character strings as "Unicode strings" in the C# documentation, thereby implying (incorrectly) that any strings that *aren't* two bytes per character are *not* Unicode. As we know from the UTF-8 encoding, this is not necessarily true - just because a string is represented as a `const char*` does not mean that it is not formed of Unicode characters. Colour me `"\xF0\x9F\x98\x92"` => ""

### The actual issue

So, for a C++ program, it must expose strings to C# using `const char*` pointers, and a C# application must marshal these strings by converting them to wide characters. Let's say I have the following C++ function, which for the sake of demonstrating C# marshaling, passes data out via a struct:

```cpp
// Header:
extern "C"
{
    struct Library_Output
    {
        const char* str;
    };

    API_FUNC void Library_GetString(Library_Output* out);
}

// Source:
extern "C"
{
    void Library_GetString(Library_Output* out)
    {
        if ( out )
        {
            // Static string literal:
            out->str = "This is a UTF-8 string. \xF0\x9F\xA4\xA0";
        }
    }
}
```

In C#, I call the function like so:

```cs
public class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct Library_Output
    {
        // This is where the marshaling type is defined.
        // C# will convert the const char* pointer to
        // a string automatically.
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)]
        public string str;
    }
    
    [DllImport("Library.dll")]
    static extern void Library_GetString(IntPtr output);

    private static void Main()
    {
        int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Library_Output));
        IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);

        Library_GetString(structPtr);
        
        // Tell C# to convert the data in the unmanaged memory
        // buffer to a managed object.
        Library_Output outputStruct =
            (Library_Output)Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr, typeof(Library_Output));
            
        Console.WriteLine(outputStruct.str);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(structPtr);
    }
}
```

Instead of printing the string to the console, what the application actually prints out is:

```
���n�
```

However, if I change the marshaling type to be `UnmanagedType.LPStr` rather than `UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str`, I get:

```
This is a UTF-8 string.
```

This is confusing to me, because [the documentation for string marshaling of structure members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings#strings-used-in-structures) states:

> UnmanagedType.LPStr: A pointer to a null-terminated array of ANSI characters.
>
> UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str: A pointer to a null-terminated array of UTF-8 encoded characters.

So ANSI string marshaling prints a UTF-8 (non-ANSI) string, but UTF-8 string marshaling prints garbage? To work out where the garbage was coming from, I had a look at what the data being printed actually was, and it appeared to be *the value of the pointer itself.*

Either the UTF-8 marshaling routine is treating the memory where the string pointer value resides as the string itself, or I'm misunderstanding something crucial about this process. My question, fundamentally, is twofold: firstly, why does the UTF-8 marshaling process not follow the string pointer properly, and secondly, what is *actually* the proper way to marshal UTF-8 strings from C++ to C#? Is it to use `LPUTF8Str`, or something else?

Comment: For completeness: which .NET version are you using?

Comment: .NET version 4.7.2, which I believe is the minimum required for `LPUTF8Str` support.

Comment: For information, on .NET 7 running at Linux, I get expected result with your LPUTF8Str code (so it prints correct string, not some garbage).

Comment: Maybe worth checking how .NET 7 behaves in your setup.